# How to change S3 XML error message in the browser?

Tags: python, xml, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-s3

When I delete an image in my S3 bucket from my python/flask app, then I try to access it via the  image url, the browser display this XML error :

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>71CFC68194E525D9</RequestId>
<HostId>
wl5InZL0Be8WTMn34ldT1csFJ2VUu5otY+FC61DQk94bgSeLMWBYhN+2Ll7iK6iBhc2DkpBWHwo=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

As expected, my image does no longer exists in my bucket but I don't know why I have this `AcessDenied` error . I need to display something more neutral like `404 not found`.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: In my opinion the error message AccessDenied is better than 404.  404 means that a HTTP URL is not found.  UserAccessGranted is an error message associated with a FILE operation.  The standard error codes are shown here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[S3 API GetObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html)

> You need the `s3:GetObject` permission for this operation. If the object you request does not exist, the error Amazon S3 returns depends on whether you also have the `s3:ListBucket`  permission.

- If you have the `s3:ListBucket` permission on the bucket, Amazon S3 will return an HTTP status code 404 ("no such key") error.
- If you don’t have the `s3:ListBucket` permission, Amazon S3 will return an HTTP status code 403 ("access denied") error.